# howi can give for each column a color in highcharts type columnrange

Tags: colors, highcharts, range

I have this categories

```
['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']
```

and for each one have a status for example S1, S2, S3 have status 1 and S4 have status 2, so i want to give for each column result a color red for status 1 and black for status 2 two

example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/9fLx97k5/
- http://jsfiddle.net/hLgqyo7y/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide the color information in the data point object.

So this:

```
[150, 300]
```

becomes:

```
{low:150, high:300, color:'red'}
```

for the points that you want to be different.

You can leave your default series color black, and then only update the points that need to be different.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/9fLx97k5/1/